# Metric in 2-components spinor space

Tags: metric-tensor, vectors, lorentz-symmetry, spinors, clifford-algebra

Consider the two components spinors (usually *Weyl spinors*): $\psi = (c_1, c_2)^{\top}$, where $c_i$ are complex numbers.  The *metric* in spinor space is usually defined with the second Pauli matrix $\sigma_y$ (many authors are adding an $i$ factor):
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
\epsilon = i \, \sigma_y = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}
The spinor scalar product is (in matrix form)
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
\langle \, \phi, \, \psi \, \rangle = \phi^{\top} \epsilon \, \psi.
\end{equation}
In particular:
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\langle \, \psi, \, \psi \, \rangle \equiv 0.
\end{equation}
It can be shown that this scalar product is invariant under rotations and Lorentz transformations.

Since $\epsilon^{\top} = -\, \epsilon$, the spinor metric is antisymmetric.

So my question is simple:  can we say that the spinor space is ***symplectic***, just from its antisymmetric metric? (like what we say for the classical phase space which is also symplectic, because its metric is also antisymmetric)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes, the vector space $V\cong \mathbb{C}^2$ for the left Weyl representation $\rho:SL(2,\mathbb{C})\to {\rm End}(V)$ is a [symplectic vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symplectic_vector_space) with symplectic structure given by the Levi-Civita tensor $\epsilon_{\alpha\beta}$. It is invariant under the group action 
   $$
   \langle \rho(g)\phi ,  \rho(g)\psi  \rangle ~=~ \phi^{\top} g^{\top} \epsilon   g\psi~=~\det(g)\phi^{\top}  \epsilon  \psi~=~\langle \phi , \psi \rangle, \qquad g~\in~SL(2,\mathbb{C}),
   $$
   of the double cover $SL(2,\mathbb{C})$ of the [restricted Lorentz group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_group#Restricted_Lorentz_group).
2. Recalling that physical left Weyl spinors $\psi^{\alpha}$ are Grassmann-odd, the antisymmetric tensor $\epsilon_{\alpha\beta}$ can be viewed as a metric on a Grassmann-odd [super-vector-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_vector_space).
3. There is a similar story for the right Weyl/complex conjugate representation $\bar{V}$.